# AWK print and color 3 variables

Tags: bash, awk

I have two AWK commands that do the equivalent of `grep -e PATTERN`and the other colors specific words in the output but doesn't filter only those lines. Can they be combined into one awk.sh file?

This one prints 3 variables (**Username**, **Group Policy**, and **Assigned IP**) :

`awk '/^Username/{print $0}/^Group/{print $0}/^Assigned/{print $0}' session.log`

So it looks like this:

`[root@localhost User]# ./find.sh
Username     : User1                  Index        : 111
Assigned IP  : 11.11.11.111           Public IP    : 22.22.22.222
Group Policy : DfltGrpPolicy          Tunnel Group : Default-VPN
Username     : User2                  Index        : 111
Assigned IP  : 11.11.11.111           Public IP    : 22.22.22.222
Group Policy : DfltGrpPolicy          Tunnel Group : Default-VPN`

The other colors those variables green and red respectively (but outputs a lot of junk, and for some reason the coloring is broken on the second variable?):

```
cat session.log | awk '{ gsub("Username", "\033[1;32m&\033[0m");
                                   gsub("Assigned IP", "\033[1;32m&\032[0m");
                                   gsub("Group Policy", "\033[1;31m&\033[0m");
                                   print }'
```

Here is the picture of colouring output:

[image: Picture of coloring output]

And here is the edited in MS Word, but this is my end goal.

[image: Edited in MS Word, but this is my end goal.]

Comment: Welcome to SO, good that you have shown us what you have tried. Request you to please post sample input and sample output in your post with code tags and let us know then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need cat to read the file. Just use awk.
2. I think you want to `sub` instead of `gsub`.
3. In Assigned IP, you have `\032[0m` but I guess you wanted `\033[0m`.
4. You can combine everything:

   ```
   awk '/^(Username|Assigned IP)/{sub("^(Username|Assigned IP)", "\033[1;32m&\033[0m"); print} /^Group Policy/{sub("^Group Policy", "\033[1;31m&\033[0m"); print}' session.log
   ```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much.
1. My mistake, noob error
2. Is gsub the wrong variable? Will be looking into this more for my own sake.
3. Yes, Typo when I was changing color values :)

Comment: @Jakob You're welcome. `gsub` is the _g_ lobal version of `sub`, it replaces all occurences instead of the first one.